# Bluffing answer reviews!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, review-audits, first-post-review

I had a little bit of spare time and I thought of going through and reviewing things on Stack Overflow.

I just had a look in an answer that was a one-liner, definitely not providing a solid solution. I am not expert on the topic and thus I clicked on the question to see other peoples comments (might have been a 4 word answer that points to the correct direction!). However, the answer has been already deleted and the OP has updated his/her question to cover that point... So naturally I went back to my review tab and clicked "No Action Needed" assuming that the author of the answer removed it. I got back the warning saying "Stop, listen, etc." and I paused for a while! But I do stand by my opinion: "No Action Needed"

Should there be another review option? Should I choose "Skip" in such cases? Thinking of it from a site management perspective "No Action Needed" is the correct answer! Either the review process or the author of the answer has already sorted out the issue... On the other hand, I am not confused or unsure to click "Skip"... The answer is missing so I am sure that no action is needed!

I do try to spend some time on every post I review focusing on being "good" to users with low rep and encourage them... But the above situation confused me. I think that a button saying "Not applicable" or "N/A", even if it is a bluff one makes more sense. What do you think? Is there a rule or official guide line (i.e. "if confused click Skip")?

Comment: Audits are designed to make sure you're paying attention, if you had chosen your original action and recommended deletion of the answer then you would have passed the audit. Actual review items will not be reviewable if the answer is deleted. If you click through and see that the answer is already deleted, it's an audit (or some craziness that it was deleted at the exact moment you loaded the review). But yeah, if you're unsure, skip. Skip is never the wrong action.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I some times load the review, go get another beer and then read the question... an active/hot thread can change in the meanwhile. Would SO refresh my review page with the next post? I am not sure but I dont think this is the case (cause a refresh/F5 leads to no posts in this category). Thus I am suggesting a "Not applicable" button that will serve for both audit purposes and handler for such cases.

Comment: Well, in that case you should always review the post based on what is shown to you in the review quque. If it is deleted, and you agree with the deletion, then you should recommend deletion. There's no need for an option to say "this post is already deleted, in case you didn't know", because the system would already know.

Comment: I see, next time!

Comment: @gnat This is a feature request asking for a "It has already been deleted" button. While the referenced question is relevant to the discussion, I don't see how this feature request is a duplicate of a general reference question about reviewing in the late answers and first posts queues.

Comment: @TinyGiant asker apparently missed to figure basics of review and review audits, which are covered in dupe target

Comment: That addresses the background information around the feature request, and is relevant to the discussion here, but it does not address the feature request itself. Therefore I do not think it is sufficiently a duplicate. Show me a question asking for an "it's already deleted" button and I'll vote to close it.

Comment: To clarify: I do request a feature that would eliminate the confusing part. On the other hand... I did not do any reading/research before going into reviewing (@gnat - tl;dr) and that's my bad... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these cases I'm always confused why the reviewer would not review the post as presented in the review queue, rather than anywhere else. Although you're right in a sense that no further action was required, the review queue doesn't ask you if this deleted post should stay deleted, it asks about the post as presented should be deleted or other action taken.

You should choose the **Recommend Deletion** option (if VLQ queue) or other appropriate option. The fact that the post was deleted but was still in the queue would set off alarm bells about this being a review audit for me.

Another scenario is that the post was deleted by the owner and could be undeleted later (perhaps in the time between the review loading for you, and you then visiting the question), but in fact the post should be permanently deleted. No Action Needed would certainly be the wrong option here.

Comment: That is a good point. I should stay on my review tab... I think your first paragraph is the correct answer to the my question and to the point (as opposed to a huge list of dos and don'ts). Thanks